# Do Latter-day Saints expect miracles from their Apostles to authenticate their callings?

Tags: lds, miracles, apostles, 2-corinthians, calling

2 Corinthians 12:11-12 (ESV):

> 11 I have been a fool! You forced me to it, for I ought to have been commended by you. For I was not at all inferior to these super-apostles, even though I am nothing. 12 **The signs of a true apostle** were performed among you with utmost patience, **with signs and wonders and mighty works**.

Acts 14:3-4 (ESV):

> 3 So they remained for a long time, speaking boldly for the Lord, who bore witness to the word of his grace, **granting signs and wonders to be done by their hands**. 4 But the people of the city were divided; some sided with the Jews and some with **the apostles**.

It is a well-known fact that the LDS Church has a [Quorum of the Twelve Apostles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quorum_of_the_Twelve_Apostles_(LDS_Church)). Do Latter-day Saints expect miracles to authenticate their callings, as 2 Corinthians 12:12 and Acts 14:3-4 seem to suggest?

---

Related:

- [How do believers in modern-day apostles interpret 2 Corinthians 12:11-12?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/86686/50422)
- [Are there any denominations that believe in contemporary apostles, and if so, how is a person called to be an apostle according to them?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/84590/50422)

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear exactly what verse 12 is saying here.  The word "with" seems to suggest that the "signs and wonders and mighty works" are something distinct from and in addition to "the signs of a true apostle", but exactly what those signs are, much like the origin of the quote in [Acts 20:35,](https://biblehub.com/acts/20-35.htm) is information not found in the Bible.

With regards to the specific question, Latter-Day Saints do not demand miracles of apostles as a validation of their authority, and typically consider that to do so would run afoul of [Matthew 16:4.](https://biblehub.com/matthew/16-4.htm)

Comment: Regarding the exegesis of verse 12, this might be of interest https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/70881/38524

Comment: Acts 14:3 is one place where signs and the reason for them is given.

Comment: @MikeBorden Acts 14:3 states that the Lord "granted signs and wonders to be done by their hands" at one specific place, but it doesn't explain what those signs and wonders are, nor does it tie them to qualifications of apostles.

Comment: @MasonWheeler It says the signs and wonders bore witness to the word of His grace, just like Mark 16:20.  It's what signs and wonders are for... to authenticate the Lord's message:  Acts 2:22, 2:43, Hebrews 2:4.